# Display expression value in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display the value of the below expression as a text in razor view.

```
@(doc.Extension ?? string.Empty).ToUpperInvariant();
```

I've tried every variant but nothing seems to work.
I know i can use a temp variable to store the value of this expression but I was wondering if there was a way to do this inline.

```
@((doc.Extension ?? string.Empty).ToUpperInvariant();)
@{@:@(doc.Extension ?? string.Empty).ToUpperInvariant();}
```

Comment: yeah it does @StriplingWarrior, do you wanna post your comment as answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use a semicolon, Razor will interpret your code as an expression instead of a statement. E.g.:

```
@((doc.Extension ?? string.Empty).ToUpperInvariant())
```