# In ASP.NET Razor, how to include model attribute in a string?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

Is there a clean way to include a string substitution inside a razor page?

That is, I have some razor code that looks like this but does not work. I feel like I'm missing some punctuation.

```
<div class='card-img'>
    <img src='images/User-@Model.Id.jpg'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display expression value in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051013/display-expression-value-in-razor)

Comment: Not a duplicated. That other questions is confusing and the answer is obtuse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current code, razor thinks the the expression `Model.Id.jpg` is some server side code it needs to execute.So you are going to get an error message saying there is no such method/property called `jpg` on whatever the type of `Id` is or there are no extension method called `jpg` in that type.

To fix the problem, you shall wrap your C# expression with an explicit `(` and `)`

```
<div class='card-img'>
    <img src='images/User-@(Model.Id).jpg'/>
</div>
```

This tells razor that `Model.Id` is the C# expression it needs to execute. The output of exuecuting that expression will pe rendered in the HTML.For example, If the value of `Model.Id` is `100`, the rendered output will be

```
<img src="images/User-100.jpg">
```

Now make adjustments to your path (src value) based on where you are storing the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use either Razor code block `@(...)` or `@Url.Content()` helper for string concatenation:

```
@* Code block string concatenation *@
<img src='images/User-@(Model.Id).jpg'/>

@* Content helper string concatenation *@
<img src='@Url.Content("images/User-" + Model.Id + ".jpg")'/>
```

Take note that `@Model.Id.jpg` doesn't work because `Id` property doesn't have member named `jpg`, since the second dot (`.`) treated as [member access expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operator).